# string to float and vice versa

Tags: php, string, increment

how can i convert it into float and then increment it and then convert back to string.

```
if($set==$Data_Id)
{
$rel='1.1.1.2';
}
```

after increment it should be like 1.1.1.3.

Please any help.

Comment: In what way is "1.1.1.3" a single floating point number? You've got three "points"!

Comment: Can I ask what behaviour you would expect with 1.1.1.9 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"1.1.1.2" is not a valid number. So you'll have to do something like this:

```
$rel = '1.1.1.2';
$relPlusOne = increment($rel);
function increment($number) {
    $parts = explode('.', $number);
    $parts[count($parts) - 1]++;
    return implode('.', $parts);
}
```

Comment: thanks and ai got the logic from your code and i have implemented with mine code , it works fine

Answer (score 2):

so crazy, it may work

```
$rel='1.1.1.2';
echo substr($rel, 0, -1). (substr($rel,-1)+1); //1.1.1.3
```

the big question is what do you want to happen if the string ends in **9** ??

Answer (score 1):

Here's a slightly different approach.

```
<?php
function increment_revision($version) {
    return preg_replace_callback('~[0-9]+$~', function($match) {
        return ++$match[0];
    }, $version);
}

echo increment_revision('1.2.3.4'); //1.2.3.5
```

Anthony.

Answer (score 0):

If this is exactly the case you need to solve, you could do it with [intval()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php), [strval()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strval.php), [str_replace()](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_str_replace.asp), [substr()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) and [strlen()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php).

```
$rel = '1.1.1.2'; // '1.1.1.2'

// replace dots with empty strings
$rel = str_replace('.', '', $rel); // '1112'
// get the integer value
$num = intval($rel); // 1112
// add 1
$num += 1; // 1113

// convert it back to a string
$str = strval($num); // '1113'
// initialize the return value
$ret = ''; 

// for each letter in $str
for ($i=0; $i<strlen($str); $i++) {
  echo "Current ret: $ret<br>";
  $ret .= $str[$i] . '.'; // append the current letter, then append a dot
}
$ret = substr($ret, 0, -1); // remove the last dot

echo "Incremented value: " . $ret;
```

This method will change 1.1.1.9 to 1.1.2.0, however. If that's what you want, then this will be fine.